# C# - class access modificators

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Does `C#` allow the following thing:

*Let's say I've got `namespace X` and `namespace X.Y`.*

How do I make my `class MyClass` in namespace `X.Y` internal to that namespace, so that `MyClass` couldn't be accessed from `namespace X`?

Comment: Two separate projects, Internal is internal to that project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) keyword makes a class "private" to the world outside an assembly, yet public to all types within the same assembly.

By placing `namespace X` and `namespace X.Y` in two separate assemblies, you can have classes in the latter namespace that is `internal` to that assembly and thus not accessible to types in the other namespace.

*Note:* just to underline the fact: there is no way you can make types internal to a *namespace*, you can only make them internal to an *assembly*. One assembly may contain internal types in both namespaces and these will be accessible to all types in that assembly, regardless of namespace. Another assembly, also containing types in both namespaces, will only be able to access the public types in the other assembly, regardless of namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you split things up into assemblies i believe.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030111.asp

Answer (score 0):

depending of you classes, you can also use nested types. It's possible only if classes in X.Y are only used by one class in X.